# GSheets: Find companies in a range that match target, and list them all

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, formula

I have companies in column A, each company has 3-10 competitors listed in columns B: F of each row. Let's say we're working on a company in A1, McDonald's. All I want to do is a list, in one cell (let's say G1), the companies from column A which list McDonald's as a competitor (in their rows in cols B: F).

I can do exactly this, with one big problem. I've duplicated my formula row (array/index/large/if/row) 5 times, but I need to increase the N for large each time, but I get the #NUM! error whenever the company isn't listed that many times. But I cannot reduce the number of times I want to accommodate since many others WILL have this many listed.

I swear this must be easy and I've overcomplicated it but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to do this and I hope I'm understanding your question. This formula should find the companies listed in column A that are also found in columns B through F.  Place the following formula in cell G1 and copy it down.

```
=iferror(join(",",filter($A$1:$A,MMULT(ARRAYFORMULA(if($A1=$B$1:$F,1,0)),TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN($B$1:$F)^0)))=1)),"")
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! If I get time I'll have to break this down and take the value from each function, which I'm sure could be useful in future, but in the meantime, super appreciate it! Upvoted and marked solved

Comment: @MarcDungey I'm glad I could help.  Probably the most confusing parts are ^0, which makes sure it always returns a 1, and the `iferror()` is to catch when `filter()` returns nothing.